# WPF Binding DateTime to an Application Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

what's the best way to bind a variable from the code behind (App.xaml.cs) to the App.xaml, so then I can refer to this resource anywhere in my application if need be.

Found this class, which make sense. I should be able to Bind the application resource to [icode]NotifyingDateTime[/icode] and it will update when that class changes.

```
public class NotifyingDateTime : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DateTime _now;

    public NotifyingDateTime()
    {
        _now = DateTime.Now;
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    public DateTime Now
    {
        get { return _now; }
        private set
        {
            _now = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Now"));
        }
    }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Now = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to bind it though, and also don't understand if the binding will execute the Class so that the DispatcherTimer will start when the application starts.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: That isn't code-behind... that is a ViewModel. You create an instance of a viewmodel and apply it to a View's (the wpf page) DataContext.

Comment: What does you mean with :"Binding to app.xaml"? The App.xaml is a defention file for you application propertys, not for the definition  of an UI element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare instance of NotifyingDateTime under Application.Resources and bind Text with Now property.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <local:NotifyingDateTime x:Key="NotifyingDateTime"/>
   <TextBlock x:Key="latestTime"
              Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource NotifyingDateTime}, Path=Now}"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Ofcourse you have to define local namespace at root of App to point to namespace where NotifyingDateTime class is defined in.

---

Now, you can use it as resource wherever you want like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource latestTime}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stab in the dark... Its not clear what you're asking, but based on the code you show (which looks like a viewmodel), you can apply an instance of it to the windows datacontext. Then any bindings in the window will link to this viewmodel and its properties.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:NotifyingDateTime></local:NotifyingDateTime>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Now}"></TextBlock>
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

be sure to update the namespace for `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"`

Things get more advanced if you want to create your view model first, then the view as you'll need to look at something like [Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro)

Comment: Tried other answer first and that worked, but thanks!